# Python way to sort tuples in a dictionary

Tags: tuples, jquery-ui-sortable, python-3.2, dictionary

Could someone explain how dictionaries are sorted and why?
The below line's output:

```py
>>> d= {(1, 2):"f", (1, 3):"f", (1, 4):"f", (1, 4):"f"}
>>> d
{(1, 2): 'f', (1, 5): 'f', (1, 3): 'f', (1, 4): 'f'}
```

and in general :

```py
>>> de= {"a":1, "b":1, "c":1, "e":1, "d":1}
>>> de
{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Lists don't behave like this so I'm confused. This is more out of curiosity I could sort it myself for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're hashtables, so they don't guarantee any sorting in any way. After all, that's why they're fast.

Comment: Aren't hashtables the same every time I execute the commands above?

Comment: @sinekonata: I'm not sure what you mean by "the same". The same in what way?

Comment: @sinekonata. Try for instance adding items (or a lot of items) to a dictionary and then removing them again. The print "order" doesn't need to change, but may change.

Comment: @Mehrdad In the way that if I execute the command on different computers at different times it will be the same order.

Comment: @sinekonata: Well I mean no one said the dictionary ***must*** give you a different order every time!! I just said there's no particular ordering guaranteed. So if you happen to observe interesting phenomena like this, be aware it wasn't done intentionally and that it doesn't imply any guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are not sorted. The language spec does not garantee that if you print a dictionary twice, that the order will be the same.
Lists on the other hand are indeed sorted.
If you want to emulate something like a dictionary with a given order of the keys, then you could use a list over tuples of keys and values.

Comment: So it's not even consistent? I tested that and apparently my test wasn't thorough

Comment: It is consistent. In the way that there is no given order.

Comment: I mean the order is not consistent along time and/or memory

Comment: Yes, the interpreter/compiler/whoever can feel free (and will be free) to organize the items as it sees most fit. To ensure fast access, to free up unused space, etc, etc. Don't rely on any apparent "order". It is like selecting something in SQL without order by clause. That's like a box full of chocolates: you never know what you gonna get.

Comment: Haha thanks. I guess the optimization is probably as you said what makes the disorder compared to lists.

Answer (score 0):

dictionaries are key/value pairs.  you can slice the dictionaries index and values into a list and sort them if you want to iterate the dictionary in sorted order.  Supposing you wanted to see the dictionaries values in sorted order